# Talend - Parsing CSV file that contains quotes around my entire row

Tags: csv, talend

I have a .csv file that I'm trying to load into Talend

My CSV file has the structure:

EventId,TppName,TppDescription,ExcludeFlag,ExclusionRationale

1,Author,Good,Y,Y

"2,Author,""The member did not sign in successfully. Missing Info, Birthdate, etc"",Y,Y"

On the second row of the .CSV file the entire row is double quoted. So I'm unable to parse that row and it skips reading that line
I use a tFileInputDelimited into a tDbOutPut.

Is there any way around this?

Tried using escape chars and text enclosures but nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a number of options:

1. Change whatever process is creating your csv file to create it as a     valid csv file - which it isn't at the moment
2. Create a Talend job that calls an external process that cleans the file - what that process would be and how it would work would depend on the OS you are running
3. Create a Talend job that reads each row as a single record, cleans it, and then writes it back to a file